# Parse xml with special characters in GROOVY

Tags: xml, groovy, special-characters

I want reads an xml and then I have to do insert on database.
My problem is when a value contains special characters.

```
def xmlResponse = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <nm>
        <item>
            <Row>
               <cod>1</cod>
               <desc>RPAS <Management></desc>
            </Row>
            <Row>
               <cod>110</cod>
               <desc>FIGHTER3 & SIMULATION</desc>
            </Row>
       </item>
   <nm>"""
```

My code is:

```
  def parser = new XmlSlurper()
  def xmlPars = "${xmlResponse}".replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
  xmlPars2 = "${xmlPars}".replaceAll("<Management>", "&lt;"+"<Management"+"&gt;")
  def xml = parser.parseText("${xmlPars2}")
```

This works only for the string 'Management' and not for all cases, because if I do the replace of all '<' and '>' than the parser return an error.

Can you help me to write a code that works always?

I don't want escape these characters (if is possible) because my insert should contain the string as well as.

Comment: It is best to fix that problem with the XML. What you are trying to parse is not XML because those characters either need to be escaped, replaced with entities, or the value wrapped with CDATA. Trying to work around those issues is going to be problematic and at some point, it will likely fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not a valid xml, and what you are doing - trying to fix the result of incorrect xml formatting. better to fix place where you are building this xml...

however there is an easy way that could work for you:

```js
def xmlResponse = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <nm>
        <item>
            <Row>
               <cod>1</cod>
               <desc>RPAS <Management></desc>
            </Row>
            <Row>
               <cod>110</cod>
               <desc>FIGHTER3 & SIMULATION</desc>
            </Row>
       </item>
   </nm>"""
//let's convert each <desc>...</desc>
//  to      <desc><![CDATA[...]]></desc>
//  then value inside CDATA does not require xml escaping
xmlResponse = xmlResponse.replaceAll('<desc>','<desc><![CDATA[').replaceAll('</desc>',']]></desc>')

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlResponse)
```